# SMTP Error 451 4.1.0

Tags: smtp

I'm adressing to you guys because I'm having a problem when sending an e-mail to a specific adress, I'm getting this message :

> Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 451 4.1.0 Recipient unknown

I looked for what it could be but couldn't find what the 4.1.0 code stands for . When I browse about the "Recipient unknown" the answers I find are about the SMTP error 500 which looks pretty confusing to me. At this point i'm trying to understand what the 4.1.0 code means for SMTP error 451 , and try to guess why I'm having this error.

Any help here would be higly appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3463

X.1.0   Other address status: Something about the address specified in the message caused this DSN.

And the SMTP server even told you what: unknown recipient.

Comment: Usefull link , thx a lot !

Answer (score 0):

The following smtp enhanced status codes usually means Invalid recipients

- 4.1.0
- 4.1.1
- 5.1.0
- 5.1.1

Refer to the [Enumerated Status Codes](https://www.iana.org/assignments/smtp-enhanced-status-codes/smtp-enhanced-status-codes.xhtml#smtp-enhanced-status-codes-3)